# findbyID returns optional . setting this object to another object cause error

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, option-type, crud-repository

```
    
    public String addStudyProgram(){
        
        Optional<StudyProgram> program = studyProgramRepository.findById(1);        

            Student student = new Student();        
            student.setStudentName("Mushashi");
            
            student.setProgram(program);    // error The method setProgram(StudyProgram) in the type Student is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<StudyProgram>)   
        
        return "Done";
    }
```

student and program are DTO ,
if i change setProgram(StudyProgram) method to setProgram(Optional)
then it interfere with database scheme. what will be the solution ?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is no program with id 1?

Comment: Hello,  program.get() ? The type of program is Optional. In Order to get the StudyProgram. you need to call the get function and handle the case of null. See this doc https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

program is Optional, use program.get() for getting object value :
student.setProgram(program.get());
Before make get(), you should check if we have a result: if(program.isPresent()) { student.setProgram(program.get());}

Answer (score 0):

`Optional<Object>` is not the actual `Object`. You can use `obj.get()` if you're sure that the value is present in the `Optional`. To avoid such an occurrence and be null safe, you can use `obj.orElse(defaultValue)` which will return the `defaultValue` as an `Object` instance.